# Caret (cursor) is not displayed in cmd Windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, user-interface

The command line caret (cursor) is not displayed at command line window.

When console is opened I can manipulate with caret: move it and edit command, but it isn't shown. Sometimes it displays as blinking **black** caret (look at `d` symbol).

[image]

I've already ran command `reg.exe query "hkcu\console" /v cursorsize` and its result is `0x19`.

Comment: Cursor will disappear when focus is not on that window, but i assume that is not your issue?

Comment: @Moab yep, it doesn't appear even in focus.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wield bug where cursors become black in consoles. You may solve this by simply changing the console background to white or other color distinguishable from the black cursor.

However on the latest build 18262, the cursor can completely disappear in applications like vim on WSL, which I still did't find any solutions.

***UPDATE***:
All those problems are now solved after insider build 18267

Comment: I'm using 19044.2006 and I still have this issue.  It started occurring within the last month.  Things I've done recently:  I've installed VS2022 (still using VS2019) and used Git Bash (MINGW64) a couple days ago and haven't restarted yet, maybe that has something to do with it.  Installed Azure CLI, that is about all I can think of.  I've tried messing around with background, cursor colors, all kinds of settings and it does nothing.

Comment: Oh, doing a lot of docker development too.  I only mention that because visual studio sometimes outputs different color text for info, warn, etc in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Check the option "Cursor colors" in Terminal tab of properties. Mine was saying "Use Color" and was set5 to black. Changed it to "Inverse Colors" and fixed the issue.